# Linq to get list of custom objects where a certain value contained within dictionary property equals a specific value

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am struggling to solve this issue and have searched multiple ways and cannot seem to find an answer. I inherited this app from someone else and need to add a couple features to the app. I have not worked much with dictionaries and linq before, so I have been searching and trying to gain knowledge to do what I need to do.

There is a class with the following properties(removed some properties not necessary for this discussion):

```
class EmailRecord
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> emails = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    public string RecordID { get; set; }
```

[followed by additional properties and constructors...]

When the objects are created, the emails Property would have a template string in the key, and a list of strings containing email addresses in the values. For my purposes, I do not need to know what is in the key.

I have a list of EmailRecord objects called allRecords. I need to query allRecords to get a list of all EmailRecord objects where the emails dictionary property's list of values contains a specific email address I have stored in a variable called recipientEmail. The key doesn't matter, and it doesn't matter how many times the email shows up. I just need the instance of the object included in the results if the email shows up anywhere in the values of the emails property. In an instance of EmailRecord, the emails dictionary property may have two keys and within each of those keys, multiple emails in a list of strings for the value. I don't need to limit to a specific key, I just need to know if an email exists anywhere within the list of email strings anywhere in that dictionary.

I've tried a few things, with the latest being this (which doesn't work):

```
var results = EmailRecords
    .SelectMany(x => x.emails)
    .Where(x => x.Value.Contains(recipientEmail));
```

The above just seems to be returning the dictionary property, not the entire object.

I want to be able to loop through the results with something like this:

```
foreach (EmailRecord foundRecord in results) {
    ...do work here
}
```

Any thoughts or suggestions to assist me as I am trying to learn Linq? Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: So you want to loop through the `List<string>` in the whole dictionary and check if it contains `recipientEmail`? and if it does, do some works on it?

Comment: I want to get a result list of EmailRecord objects where a specific email  is anywhere in that emails dictionary. I would then be looping through that result set. Does that make sense?

Comment: But I don't see any `List<EmailRecord>` variable in your sample code to loop through

Comment: So if EmailRecords (list of EmailRecord objects) has 3 EmailRecord objects and say the first two objects has "test@test.com" as one of the values in the emails dictionary of the object and the third object does not have that email show up at all, then the link query should give me results with just the first two objects.  That's what in trying to accomplish and can't figure out.

Comment: Ok. Check my updated answer

Comment: Sorry I didn't show the code where I declared it, it would be List <EmailRecord> EmailRecords = new List <EmailRecord>();

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop through `EmailRecord` objects which one of its `emails` property values contains `recipientEmail`, then you need to have a list of `EmailRecord` first. Then search throught them. following should do the trick.

```
List<EmailRecord> EmailRecords = new List<EmailRecord>();

//Fill the EmailRecords somewhere

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> emailfoundRecord in 
                  EmailRecords.emails.Where(x => x.Value.Contains(recipientEmail)))
 {
   //do work here       
 }
```

Comment: Thank you Alex. When I tried yours, for the portion emailfoundRecord in EmailRecords.emails, it didn't recognize email. I am unsure why and was troubleshooting that when I saw Corey's post and am trying that solution now as well.

Comment: Since `EmailRecords` is a `List` you'll need to enumerate it to get at the `emails` member.  Best to test the code in something like LINQPad to see that it works before posting.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `EmailRecords.SelectMany(x => x.Emails)` what you get back is an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>>` or similar.  Obviously this is not what you're after for your result since it strips away all that other information.

With LINQ the first thing to consider at each stage is what you are expecting to get out of the query.  In this case the query results should be an enumeration of `EmailRecord` instances which is also what we're feeding in.  Filtering that list is most simply done with the `Where` method, so that's where you should do all the work

Next decide on your filter criteria and write the filter predicate to suit.  For any given `EmailRecord` we want to find out if any of the dictionary entries contains a particular email address.  Since the dictionary values are lists we'll use `Contains` to do the actual comparison, and `Any` to test the dictionary itself.

Which looks like this:

```
var filtered = EmailRecords.Where(e => 
    e.Emails.Any(kv => 
        kv.Value.Contains(recipientEmail)
    )
);
```

This works because a dictionary is also an enumerable, with each entry in the enumeration being a key/value pair.

Using `Any` will stop when it finds a single matching entry instead of continuing to the end of the `Emails` dictionary for every `EmailRecord` instance.  If there are a lot of emails and you're expecting a high number of selections then this might save some time.  Probably not however, since generally this sort of structure doesn't have a lot of duplicate email addresses in it.

Depending on how often you want to do this however it might be quicker to build a lookup and query that.  Assuming that your `EmailRecords` list changes infrequently and you are doing a lot of this sort of lookup, you could get a large speedup.

I'll use a `Dictionary<string, EmailRecord[]>` for the lookup because it's (fairly) simple to build once we get a list of all of the pairs of email address and `EmailRecord` objects:

```
var emailReferences = EmailRecords.SelectMany(e => 
    e.Emails.SelectMany(kv => 
        kv.Value.Select(v => 
            new { address = v, record = e }
        )
    )
);

var lookup = 
    emailReferences
    .GroupBy(i => i.address, i => i.record)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToArray());
;
```

From this you will be able to locate an email address and get its referencing `EmailRecord` instances fairly simply and quickly:

```
EmailRecord[] filtered = null;
lookup.TryGetValue(recipientEmail, out filtered);
```

This will be faster per lookup than the LINQ equivalent above, but the setup could consume a fair amount of time and memory for large lists.  If you have small or frequently changing lists (since the lookup has to be regenerated or at least invalidated at each change) then this won't improve your program's speed.

---

As a completely unsolicited aside, here's an extension method I use when dealing with dictionaries that have `List<>` as the value:

```
public static partial class extensions
{
    public static Dictionary<TKey, List<TElem>> Add<TKey, TElem>(this Dictionary<TKey, List<TElem>> dict, TKey key, TElem value)
    {
        List<TElem> list;
        if (dict.ContainsKey(key))
            list = dict[key];
        else
            dict[key] = list = new List<TElem>();

        list.Add(value);
        return dict;
    }
}
```

It helps make your adds simpler and easier to read.

Comment: Corey, thank you for your answer, it worked very well and accomplished what I needed! I also appreciate all the background, it really helps as I am learning this, thanks!

Comment: I figure it's better to give more detailed answers when it looks like someone is learning how stuff works.  Better than one-line "do this" type answers :)  Also good to give alternatives to show how everything has multiple ways to solve it depending on the requirements.